# CSS dropdown not displaying properly, down down is invisible

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have put a dropdown in my app for mobile users. The dropdown button is working correctly and the dropdown content/links are clickable as expected. The problem is that the dropdown content/links are invisible to the user.

I have search everywhere for the answer and have tried re-writing my code in all my stye sheets. My debugging shows the navigation is still working correctly with no errors.

I've attached my code:

HTML:

```
<!--Implementing mobile friendly nav-->
<center>
  <div class="mobileShow">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">...</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'DASHBOARD', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                array('label'=>'VIDEOS', 'url'=>array('/site/videos')),
                array('label'=>'CONTACT', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                array('label'=>'REGISTER', 'url'=>array('site/register'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'LOGIN', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'LOGOUT', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)),
            )); 
          ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px){ .mobileShow { display: none;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px){ .mobileShow { display: block;}}
.dropbtn {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #009999;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.dropbtn:hover {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
   background-color:#00b3b3;
   transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    clear:both;
    right: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:460px;
    height: 200px;
}
</style>
```

Here is what it is displaying when the user hovers the button:
Before hover->   https://i.stack.imgur.com/eljyg.png
After hover->   https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzfWq.png

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the opacity for .dropdown-content. 
making it look

```
.dropdown-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-height: 650px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    will-change: width, height;
}
```

Comment: Hi mate, just figured it out myself. By adding the following

 opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;

Answer (score 0):

Fixed CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px){ .mobileShow { display: none;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px){ .mobileShow { display: block;}}
.dropbtn {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #009999;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.dropbtn:hover {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
   background-color:#00b3b3;
   transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    clear:both;
    right: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:460px;
    height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

Adding opacity: 1; & visibility: visible; worked.